# Apache reverse proxy encodes characters

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, encoding, bugzilla

I have setup apache reverse proxy to serve bugzilla from behind a firewall with following config

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /bugzilla http://88.88.88.75/bugzilla nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /bugzilla http://88.88.88.75/bugzilla
<location /bugzilla/>
        ProxyPassReverse /
        RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
</location>
```

But the problem is that when the request hits bugzilla the search terms are all encoded and bugzilla can't find anything

E.g. "`search term`" becomes "`search%20term`" when it reaches bugzilla as it is encoded to be "`search%2520term`" by the proxy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have ended using mod_rewrite to do the proxy and told it not to encode chars. Now my config looks like

```
ProxyRequests Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/bugzilla-rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 0
RewriteRule ^/bugzilla/(.*)$ http://88.88.88.75/bugzilla/$1 [P,NE]

ProxyPass /bugzilla http://88.88.88.75/bugzilla nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /bugzilla http://88.88.88.75/bugzilla

<location /bugzilla/>
        ProxyPassReverse /
        RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
</location>
```

I don't know if all lines are needed but it works and I am not touching it